# Peugeot 206 indicator not working properly

Tags: peugeot, turn-signal

In my Peugeot 206 my indicator isn't working. If I indicate I go too the right, the indicator will turn on (with the correspending sound) for about 3 seconds and then it will turn off. If I want to turn it on again I'd have to find the 'sweet spot'.

What are possible solutions? Is this something I can fix myself (I do have airbags)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what happens when the hazard light is switched on. If hazard works correctly then the problem could be with the combination switch(light). It is better to get it replaced at the workshop is my suggestion

Comment: Hazard light works. I will get it looked at. Thanks!